# MSSQL Multiple FKs in table: cannot have multiple cascade/set nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, constraints

I have a fairly simple design, as follows:

[image]

What I want to achieve in my `grouping_individual_history` is marked in red:

- when a session is deleted, I want to cascade delete the grouping_history....
- when a grouping is deleted, I just want the child field to be nullified

It seems that MSSQL will not allow me to have more than one FK that does *something else* than *no action* ... It'll complain with:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_grouping_individual_history_grouping' on table 'grouping_individual_history' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I've already read this post (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/), although it's not quite the same scenario it seems to me.

I've tried doing a `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on my `grouping` table, but it wont accept it, because in turn, my grouping table has another FK (fkSessionID) that does a cascade delete... So, the fix would be to **change it all, in all affected tables with FKs**. The chain is long though, and we cannot consider it.

For one thing, can someone explain to me why SQL Server is giving me the issue for this very simple scenario in the first place? I just don't understand it.

Is there another workaround I could use (besides just removing the foreign key link from my grouping_individual_history table)?

Comment: The simple fact is that SQL Server does not support multiple cascade paths. If you need them, you need to implement the solutions yourself, either with `TRIGGER`s or `PROCEDURE`s.

Comment: Your data model is incoherent... Break the cycle at the session relationship

Comment: I don't see how else to change my data model: 1 session to many groups; 1 group to many individuals. The individual_history table will have PASSED group information for individual within a session (a.k.a. the individual got ungrouped). If the group gets deleted from the session, I need to keep the history (thus the need for sessionID in my history table). 

@Larnu Yes, using trigger seems to work. However no-go for us because of all the FKs in linking tables. I've ended up doing NO ACTION on delete, but allowed null in the fkPrevGroupingID. Code takes care of setting to null on Group delete.